# Using Android C2DM with a different application package

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I develop apps for clients. To be able to add C2DM functionality to the apps, I need a C2DM registration. So far I've used the client's registrations and their account so I could test and they could take it in to production. This is cumbersome for 2 reasons: I need access to their account which is undesired, and I have to wait until they have their account set up, which is often a time consuming process for larger organisations.

To ease development, I thought I'd register my own C2DM account. I now run into a problem where the package name of the project I create and my registered package name do not match, causing C2DM messages to never arrive in the app.

So essentially I want the following:

- Change the manifest file in such a way that it uses com.devcompany.package for C2Dm but com.clientcompany.package for the app itself.
- Send messages using the com.devcompany.package registered account.

So far I've been only able to get this to work if I rename the entire application package to com.devcompany.package, which is a hassle.

I've tried various combinations of the registration intents and permissions, but none seem successful.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried setting signature verification to false?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. However, you could create a dummy app `com.devcompany.package` with the sole purpose of forwarding your C2DM messages...